# Re-binding the 'ng-click' directive when it's located within 'ng-view'

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using the AngularJS directive: `ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();"` to keep a bootstrap dropdown menu open beyond the first subsequent click. It works fine.

When I use `ng-view` to route to that same element however, the dynamically rendered version of the dropdown loses its `ng-click` functionality. How can I re-bind this element?

**EDIT**: At the request of below comments I've created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9lCs7UuvR8KoLRRvX17m?p=preview). Currently this pre-`ng-view` version behaves as I desire, i.e. when a user clicks the bootstrap dropdown button, the dropdown-menu element appears and remains open until the user clicks outside of the menu (or once more on the dropdown button). I've accomplished this behavior by amending the `.dropdown-menu` tag in the html with `ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();"`.

What I've discovered is that as soon as I try to add the `ngRoute` resource module into my app (as a precursor to coding the `$routeProvider` component), the `ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();"` directive will immediately fail. Here is where I'm adding `ngRoute` within the above Plunk:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

Can someone tell me what's going on and how I can fix it? I ultimately want to render the button through a view, but to do so **with** the `ng-click` directive bound and functioning.

**EDIT2**: User has provided a working solution in below comments. By removing the `#` from  `href` tags the `ng-click` isn't skipped. Implemented this solution in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9lCs7UuvR8KoLRRvX17m?p=preview) for posterity's sake.

Comment: can you set plunk to reproduce that?

Comment: Does clicking on the element show the menu or not after you use `ng-view`?

Comment: Either add a plunk or try manually to re-$compile element to see if it works. can't think of other solution according to your description

Comment: @KostiaMololkin: Done. Please see above edit.

Comment: @GregL: Yes, it does. I've created a Plunk above.

Comment: @Linial: Plunk added above.

Comment: @RobJ : Thanks for the response. Tried your suggestion and my element now looks as follows: `<ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" ng-if="status.isopen" role="menu">`. Regardless, when I add `ngRoute` as a dependency to my app, the `ng-click` still fails.

Comment: Try removing the # from the Ng-href, just use ng-href=""

Comment: @RobJ : This appears to work! Thank you. Let me now go the rest of the way and render the button in a partial view to see if it gets around the original problem I was having.

Comment: @RobJ : Works perfectly. If you want to put your answer below I'll approve it and link my solution plunk above. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The href="#" in the a elements is causing a page navigate, try using href="" instead.

Comment: I'd like to add that the `href="#"` only started to caused a problem **after** I added `ngRoute` as an app dependency. Which makes sense I suppose since it activates the routing module and allows each link to refresh the page prior to the execution of any other `ngClick` functionality. Without `ngRoute` the `ngClick` functionality executes OK.